# Add Transparent Image on top of other Images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I need to add a Transparent image on top of all images on a page.  The goal is if a user were to do a simple right click and save of an image, they would save the transparent image.

I do realize this is not a guaranteed method and that none exist to prevent image theft but simply a measure that a client wants added to prevent your average non tech person from saving images.

- Using JavaScript I would like to find all images or all images within a certain Div.
- Apply a new image overlay on top of these images that will have the same width and height of the image they are covering

I am not sure how to do this with JavaScript and was hoping someone would have a quick fix or example.  I was unable to find anything so far on Google or SO.  Appreciate any help

I have this JS which gets all images on a page so far...

```
// Get all images on a Page
function checkimages() {
     var images = document.images;
     for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
        var img =images[i].src;

       // Add new transparent image on top of this image
       alert(img);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to work with jQuery (or similar library) to keep things easier. I would even write a small jquery extension to make it easy to recycle the code, and apply it on any div (or other wrapper), wich child images you want to be overlayed.

My code would look something like this:

```
// jquery plugin to create overlays
// src is the url of the overlay image
// apply to any container that contains images to be overlayed
$.fn.overlayImages = function(src) {
    // loop trough the images
    $(this).find('img').each(function() {
        // cache some variables
        var $img =  $(this);
        var $parent = $img.parent();
        // make the parent relative, if not yet absolute or fixed, for easy positioning
        if ($parent.css('position') !== 'fixed' && $parent.css('position') !== 'absolute') {
            $parent.css('position', 'relative');            
        }
        // get the position of the image
        var position = $img.position();
        // clone the image
        var $overlay = $img.clone();
        // set the styling, based on the img, for exact positioning
        $overlay.css({
            top: position.top,
            left: position.left,
            position: 'absolute',
            width: $img.width(),
            height: $img.height()
        });
        // change the src attribute for the overlay
        $overlay.attr('src', src);
        // insert the overlay to the DOM
        $overlay.insertAfter($img);
    });
}

// when the DOM is loaded (not just ready, the images need to be there to copy their position and size)
$(window).load(function() {
    // apply the overlay plugin to the wrapper of the images
    $('#replace-images').overlayImages("http://www.riptideinnovations.com/images/watermark.png");
});
```

I added the step by step explanation inside the code as comments, but do feel free to ask if you want any further explanation.

I set up a small fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/pP96f/6/

Comment: jQuery, is not "easier". It's a tool, that has to be learned; it's an API and not as flexible as writing your own JavaScript. I advise, don't use it. I suggest to learn something that has been in use since the dawn of the internet and the www. What I hate most, "your code has been deprecated", that's the API notice you get when you use a packaged/hi-jacked set of useless wanna-be code. Ask a question about JS and get jQuery. When will it stop?

Comment: @ejbytes, you do realise this answer is 7 years old right? Trust me, it really used to be easier to work with jQuery when trying to write cross browser JavaScript. Luckily times have changed, and I tend to agree with you. The days of jQuery are over, and vanilla JavaScript would do just fine in this case, and I would advise against it as well!

Comment: I do realize this. But when I get stuck, I have to go to Gaggle search and StackOverflow is in the top results... just tired of seeing jQuery. Take care bud :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help, but you could make your images all div's with backgrounds like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('<your_image>');"></div>
```

Comment: Yes that's not possible as I am not able to change any of the HTML, that's why I am looking for a full JS solution

Comment: This would require a lot more work to set div width and heights/etc.